# What do you call someone looking for a job?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to compose a sentence, and I am currently stuck for the right word. I am trying to say:

> In a job interview, the audience would be the employer and the ---------

That is the word I am looking for. I cannot put "employee" as he has not been employed yet. Is there a single word for someone looking for a job? "Job-seeker?"

Comment: It's, um, linguistics

Comment: "Unemployed" ;-)

Comment: Thursagen, in what way does it's "linguistics" make "audience" correct in this case? I'm intrigued.

Comment: It's kind of metalanguage. It's a technical term for the person/persons receiving the act of communication

Comment: Maybe the word "audience" has some specialized meaning among linguists, but for general use, the word is inappropriate here. An "audience" is a person or persons who are listening to an event, not the participants. "In a job interview, the PARTICIPANTS are the employer and the applicant." If there is an audience at a job interview, that would mean people watching without participating in the interview. Normally "audience" is used for people watching a play or movie or listening to a concert, that sort of thing.

Comment: Fresher....... :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you looking for **[applicant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/applicant)**?

Another synonym is **candidate** (but with a broader meaning).

The Merriam-Webster definition is:

> **ap·pli·cant** - noun \ˈa-pli-kənt\
>
> - Definition
>       Applicant: one who applies <a job applicant>
> - Examples
>       *We interviewed 30 qualified applicants for the job.*
>       *have numerous applicants for the job*
> - First Known Use 
>       1776

N.B.: 1776? What kind of job could that have been?

Comment: I think that jobs existed before 1776, even if that usage of the word 'job' did not.

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ, My mistake. I was hinting at the American Revolution but G. Washington actually took office in 1789, 13 years and a few battles after the Declaration of Independence.  So that *applicants* hadn't probably stepped forward in 1776.

Answer (score 5):

The person could be a candidate or an interviewee. He/ she could also be referred to as a prospective employee.

Comment: "Prospective employee" sounds good. Could you compress it into one word?

Comment: @Thursagen:  Not all concepts have single words that accurately describe the concept in every language.

Answer (score 0):

I would lean towards interviewee in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The term for this is candidate.

Comment: Why is this the only term? Can you provide more details? Can you provide any references that backup your answer. Did you know that two other answers also mention "candidate"?